# Вывод в label сумму цифр числа

Tags: c#

Каждая из 3-х функций вычисляет сумму цифр чисел, которые выбираются из 3-х ComboBox-ов при нажатии на кнопку в Label4 отображается 0

```
     int SumD(int d)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        while (d > 0)
        {
            sum = sum + (d % 10);
            d = (d / 10);
        }
        return d;
    }

     int SumM(int m)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        while (m > 0)
        {
            sum = sum + (m % 10);
            m = (m / 10);
        }
        return m;
    }

     int SumY(int y)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        while (y > 0)
        {
            sum = sum + (y % 10);
            y = (y / 10);
        }
        return y;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int d, m, y, allsum;

        d = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text);
        y = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
        m = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text);

        allsum = SumD(d) + SumM(m) + SumY(y);
        label4.Text = allsum.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функциях `SumD`, `SumM` и `SumY` надо возвращать `sum`, а не `d`, `m` и `y`.

Answer (score -1):

Я, прстите, не пишу  на диезах, но алгоритм в трех экземплярах - это нечто...

Что мешает:
- сделать единую ф-цию `SumDMY`;
- внести `Convert` в ее скобки;
- объединить комбики в массив;
- проитерировать его, суммируя результаты,
- и выплюнуть результат куда хочется ...
???

Ну, примерно так на VB6:

```
Private Sub sb_CbxArr_Test()
Dim k&, lSum&
Dim sSum$

    lSum = 0

    With cbx_Arr
        For k = .LBound To .LBound
            lSum = lSum + fn_Sum(.Item(k).Text)
        Next ' k
    End With ' cbx_Arr

    sSum = CStr(lSum) ' or Format$(lSum, "your_mask")

    ' do any you want

End Sub

Private Function fn_Sum(pVal$) As Long
Dim lVal&, lSum&

    lVal = CLng(pVal) ' or Val(pVal)
    lSum = 0

    Do While (lVal > 0)
        lSum = lSum Mod 10
        lVal = lVal \ 10
    Loop

    fn_Sum = lSum

End Function
```

Если, конечно, я ничего не напутал:
- в операторах `C# % и /` --> `VB6 Mod и \`
- с комбобоксами VB6 - не имел дела :)

Но суть-то ясна, имо ... 
.